# Is it possible to exclude files and folder that begin with $ from Windows 2008 R2 DFS replica?

Tags: windows, dfs, dfs-r, exclude

If I replicate by DFSR users redirected folders all folders replicated have their own **$RECYCLE.BIN** directory and inside that directrory files are renamed as **$XXXXX.YYY**. I don't want to replicate them, it's only wasting bandwidth.

**How it could be possible to filter files and folders that begin with $ (dollar) character?**

File and directory exclusion seem not to work with "$*" and "$RECYCLE.BIN".

Comment: You only replicate files if they change. When files are deleted and moved to the recycle ebin, all you doing essentially is replicating the fact that files got renamed. If you choose not to replicate these files, then depending on which replica your end users connect to, they may or may not see files in recycle bin. I don't think that's a good end user experience.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with replication filters.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753409.aspx  In DFS Management, go to the replication group, select the Replicated Folders tab, right click the replicated folder and in properties under general you can add a CSV list of filters.

In mine I have `~*,*.bak,*.tmp`